# What's with the speaker's initial thing?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

If you've ever been to a math talk (at least in pure maths in the UK) you've probably seen something like this written:

> Theorem (E.--Johnson--Smith, 2022+) The XYZ conjecture is true.

At some point you probably realized that writing "E." is the speaker's way of being... modest? lazy? Anyway, it is the initial of the speaker's surname and it means this is the speaker's work (joint work in this case), and probably the thing being spoken about.

What is the origin of this practice? Is it old? Is it widespread? Is it used in other fields? Should we really bother?

Occasionally for variety I have written "speaker" instead of "E.".

Comment: see https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/161640

Comment: I like the idea of using two initials (first and last name)! It makes the abbreviation look more like a person and less like a mystery. Now that we know this is common in physics, I think we can all start doing that in mathematics also without feeling ashamed.

Comment: See especially the [answer by Christian](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/161644/68420) in the question Carlo mentioned. It's a bit of an unspoken rule within math academia.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! Pretty much what I expected as to the reasons, and good to know it's reasonably common in physics too. I still wonder about how old etc.

Comment: I've always seen this as a way of getting across "I did this" without having to actually say so out loud.

Comment: On [math.se]: [The convention for speakers to refer to themselves at the board with a single initial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1022281). This question was later crossposted to [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/8491).

Comment: I find it convenient to use both my initials.

Comment: I heard that there is/was one mathematician, whose last name consisted only of a single letter. This convention made it really awkward to cite his results, especially if your surname starts with his name.

Comment: Referring to yourself in the third person puts you in a lot of bad company.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning, don't you [mean](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433332/whats-with-the-speakers-initial-thing#comment1115730_433332) "referring to oneself in the third person puts one in a lot of bad company"? 

Comment: To partially answer the historical question, I'm confident that the practice was uncommon back when I received my Ph.D. in 1995. I don't know when the practice was adopted, but I do remember one talk in which the author put his full last name in parentheses next to his theorem, and then digressed for 30 seconds to express his annoyance with the increasingly common practice of using an initial only. Unfortunately, I don't remember exactly when this talk occurred.

Comment: @LSpice Tim Chow thinks she meant that [illeism may be used to show idiocy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illeism#In_literature).

Comment: A single initial suggests you're embarrassed by the theorem. That's why I prefer the alternative "The Esteemed [full title] [my full name]" written carefully in large, cursive script.